# Find EL equations for $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\left[ab^2\dot{\phi}_1^2+\frac{1}{2}ab^2\dot{\phi}_2^2+ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)\right]dt$

Tags: optimization, euler-lagrange-equation

We have $$J[\phi_1,\phi_2] = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \left[ab^2 \dot{\phi}_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}ab^2 \dot{\phi}_2^2 + ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2) \right] dt$$ where $\phi_1=\phi_1(t), \phi_2=\phi_2(t)$, $a,b$ constant.

The Euler-Lagrange equations for several functions of a single variable are 
$\displaystyle 0= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_i} - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{\phi}_i},$
where 
$$f(t,\phi_1, \phi_2, \dot{\phi}_1, \dot{\phi}_2) =ab^2 \dot{\phi}_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}ab^2 \dot{\phi}_2^2 + ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2).$$

I have
\begin{align}
0 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_1} - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\phi}_1}\\
&= ab^2\phi_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( 2ab^2 \dot{\phi}_1 \right)\\
&= ab^2\phi_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - ab^2 \phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - 2ab^2\ddot{\phi}_1\\
0 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{\phi}_2}\\
&= ab^2\phi_1\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)+ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(ab^2 \dot{\phi}_2)\\
&= ab^2\phi_1\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)+ab^2\phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2)-ab^2 \ddot{\phi}_2
\end{align}
as the system of 2 second order ode's:
\begin{align*}
0&=\phi_2\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - \phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2) - 2\ddot{\phi}_1 \\
0&=\phi_1\cos(\phi_1 - \phi_2)+\phi_1\phi_2\sin(\phi_1 - \phi_2)- \ddot{\phi}_2.
\end{align*}

> Am I on the right track? Are there two EL equations, one for each $\phi_j?$

Comment: What's your question? Your work looks good so far.

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to make the $\ddot{\phi}_j$ the subjects of their ELEs, thereby cancelling a factor of $ab^2$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister my only question was if I was headed on the right track i.e. if it's correct that there's an EL eqn for each function.

Comment: Then you should definitely include that in your question. You are correct that there's a separate EL equation for each $\phi_j.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track, and there are two EL equations, one for each $\phi_j.$ I don't envy you solving that system of ODE's, as it's highly non-linear and coupled.